# How to: height child gives same height parent ...?

Tags: css

What to do to get a height for nav the same as height (padding) of nav li a ... !?

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 0.8em;
    font-family:"courier new"; courier; sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
nav ul li a {
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: #bf2e1f;
}
```

Fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/redfox52/HbrkA/

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking because you are going to create this programmatically?  The obvious answer to me from a strictly CSS sense is, write the same padding line in the nav { } block as in the ul li a { } block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top/bottom padding on the links should be 0:

```
padding: 0 0.5em
```

If you want to add padding to the links, make them block elements ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/4NvDf/)).

Comment: Plus a minor tweak ... put overflow:hidden on `nav` because otherwise `li a` slips slightly out of the box ...

Answer (score 0):

Oops, of course ...

nav { overflow: auto; }

will do the trick too ... which kind of padding (also padding-bottom) on `a` ... height `nav` will follow ... :)

Thanks all for helping me!

Comment: ... mmm, and there we have a scrollbar > http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp ... so `display: inline-block` it will be.